# cyrus-sasl-lib issue on CentOS 5.3 (while installing GUI)

Tags: centos, gnome, cyrus

I am attempting to install gnome on a CentOS 5.3 Server install so that I can speed up the process that I am working on.  I ran a yum groupinstall for the x window system and gnome but I keep getting the following error.

```
Package cyrus-sasl-plain needs cyrus-sasl-lib = 2.1.22-4, this is not available.
Package cyrus-sasl needs cyrus-sasl-lib = 2.1.22-4, this is not available.
Package cyrus-sasl-plain needs cyrus-sasl-lib = 2.1.22-4, this is not available.
Package cyrus-sasl needs cyrus-sasl-lib = 2.1.22-4, this is not available.
Complete!
```

First thing I checked was what version of the cyrus-sasl-lib I had installed.

```
Installed Packages
cyrus-sasl-lib.i386                      2.1.22-4               installed       
cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64                    2.1.22-4               installed       
Available Packages
cyrus-sasl-lib.x86_64                    2.1.22-5.el5           base            
cyrus-sasl-lib.i386                      2.1.22-5.el5           base
```

Anyhow know how I can get around this and install the stuff I need so that I can start a GUI on this machine?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I've just had a similar problem (when trying to install httpd-devel) and trying

```
yum -y install cyrus*
```

worked.

Comment: Works for me for the same error.